# How to detect URL changes with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

How can jQuery detect changes to a url?

For example: If a user goes to a page `site.com/faq/` nothing shows, but if he goes to `site.com/faq/#open` jquery detects it and does something.

Comment: You should have a look at the [jQuery Address plugin](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/)

Comment: @Sahil I assume he wants this so that he can use it on page load, for example to open a specific tab in a tab control. It is a handy technique to know about.

Answer (score 28):

Try This

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function(e){
 // Your Code goes here
});
```

Its working for me

Answer (score 24):

You can use the **[hashchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onhashchange)** event.

```
function hashchanged(){
  var hash = location.hash.replace( /^#/, '' );
 //your code
}

window.addEventListener("hashchange", hashchanged, false);
```

or integrate a [jquery hashchange plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/)

```
$(function(){

  // Bind the event.
  $(window).hashchange(hashchanged);

  // Trigger the event (useful on page load).
  hashchanged();

});

function hashchanged(){
 var hash = location.hash.replace( /^#/, '' );
 //your code
}
```

Comment: See also the [jQuery BBQ plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/), although that may be more complicated than the OP requires.

Comment: there is no such thing as $(window).haschange, and the question is about detecting URL change not haschange.

Comment: The `$(window).haschange` belongs to the mentioned plugin and the question is illustrated with an example by the OP

Comment: try instead:  window.addEventListener("hashchange", myHashChangeHandler, false);

Answer (score 8):

Simply look at `window.location.hash` on page load:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(window.location.hash === "open")
    {
        //Show something
    }
});
```

Or bind to the `hashchange` event of the window:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).hashchange(hashchanged);
});

function hashchanged()
{
    //Show something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if (window.location.hash) {
    // Fragment exists, do something with it
    var fragment = window.location.hash;
}
```

Just for reference, the part of a url specified by the `#` is called a 'fragment'

Answer (score 1):

If you have a url of `site.com/faq/#open`, then you can do

```
var hash = window.location.hash
```

to get `hash = 'open'`