# How to detect that the document URL has changed, using javascript and JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm implementing a browser plugin.

I want to detect the event for document url changed to another url other than the current.

Something like this [BTW, that's pseudo code]:

```
$(window).bind('documenturlchange', function() {
    alert("page document url has been changed");
});
```

How to achieve this functionality ?

BTW, `hashchange` only detects "hash parts" changed in url, but it doesn't detect a whole link change (maybe to another domain for example)

Comment: i think this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161906/handle-url-anchor-change-event-in-js

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212845/how-to-detect-url-changes-with-jquery

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you're trying to do? Maybe there's a better way.

Comment: hashchange only detect hash changes, i want to detect a full url change (maybe to another domain for example)

Comment: i don't its possible to detect the url change in tabs moreover its a security/privacy threat to detect/get/store the user's browsing activity, you can only access the URL of the current tab by using  methods to get query string !!

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the window DOM objects hashchange event to detect for change in URLs. For instance, lets say the current URL is http://yourhost.com and the new url is http://yourhost.com#changed, in this case onhashchange event will be triggered.

Reference: [HashChange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mozilla_event_reference/hashchange)

Comment: hashchange only detects "hash parts" changed in url, but it doesn't detect a whole link change (maybe to another domain for example). for example if current url is www.google.com and I moved to www.yahoo.com, this event will not be triggered