# How to detect URL changes with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that here it is answered on how to detect hashes ([How to detect URL changes with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212845/how-to-detect-url-changes-with-jquery)) but how do you detect, for example, if jQuery alters the pushState: window.history.pushState(null,null,href); now can we detect this with some sort of watch similar to the sass --watch command?

Comment: If you altering the push state why don't you just call a function at the same time to do what you need to do?

Comment: Can you use the `window.popstate` event? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onpopstate