# How to destroy variable when change URL (any browser) in JavaScript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects, dom-events

Today use this Code but this code some time not properly work

Problem : Page refresh then call `unload()` but some time user change URL directly at that time not call `unload()` because website change...

So, How to solve it in all Browser. Please Help Me

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/JavaScript">
            function unload(){
                alert("My Page unLoad - Destroy Variable");
            }

            function load() {
                alert("My Page Load");
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onLoad="load()">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onbeforeunload = unload();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't need to destroy or null variables in Javascript.  That already happens when the page changes.

Comment: Yes, You are Right. But I am use localStorage Variable So, not Destroy automatically... manually destroy it.

Comment: So you want to remove data from localStorage when you leave the page?  It simply sounds like you should be using variables instead.  If this isn't the case then you need to clearly explain what you're trying to do and what the problem is, rather than give us snippets until we finally get to the problem.

Comment: yes remove data from localStorage when you leave the page via url change....

Comment: You shouldn't be using localStorage.

Comment: it's ok no problem but not function call why??...

Comment: if function call then solve my problem

Comment: Do not use localStorage.  Use variables.

Answer (score 2):

HTTP is stateless, so on every new page the variables will begin in their uninitialised state, and all code set to run on load (ie. not in an event handler) will run.

If you are using localstorage:

Check this question on how to detect changes in the url: [How to detect URL changes with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212845/how-to-detect-url-changes-with-jquery)

Then use this to destroy it:

```
 window.localStorage.removeItem(key);
```

Comment: But I am use localStorage Variable... So, not Destroy... manually destroy

Comment: URL change at that time not work this solution. this solution already use but not proper work.