# Setting background color + opacity in js except a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When something happens I am setting body `background-color` to grey and decrease `opacity`. However that obviously changes opacity of a button as well.

What I want to achieve is when action occur, change opacity of everything except the button.

```
var highlight = $('#' + scroll).closest('div').find('button');
$('body').css('opacity', '0.2');
$('body').css('background-color', 'grey');
$(highlight).css('background-color', '#FDFF47');
$(highlight).css('opacity', '1');
```

How can that be done?

Comment: Do you mean a particular action or a general action in your HTML page?

Comment: it's basically scrolling to a div, when query =?scroll=value is passed in url, value being an id of the div it's scrolling too

Answer (score 8):

In `background-color` use `rgba()` to reduce opacity only to background. `opacity` property is not needed.

```
$('body').css('background-color', 'rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.5)');
```

**About rgba(R, G, B, A)** - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#rgb()_and_rgba()

Answer (score 3):

When you are trying to set `background` with `opacity` use `rgba` which stands for **Red,Blue, Green colors with Opacity(Alpha)** where you can pass the last parameter as opacity. use `background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2)` instead of setting `background-color: grey`. Check below snippet for reference.

```css
div {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding:50px;
}

p {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>My Text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than setting the opacity, you can set the background color with an alpha value:

```
$('body').css('background-color', 'rgba(192,192,192,0.2)');
```

Comment: none of these answers are doing what I want it to do, rgba value is set on body, but it's not darkened to make the button bright and rest of the page darker

Comment: @PrzemyslawWojtas I suspect you're getting all these same answers because the question was asked in a way that would yield them.  I might rephrase the question and show some html, explaining the effect you want on each element.

Comment: I don't think it's that hard. Set body background to greyish colour except for buttons. body is of course a whole page, but I want to highlight a specific button to give user a hint "click here"

Answer (score 0):

try with this `jquery code`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn").hover(function() {
    $("#btn").css('background-color', 'grey');
    $("#btn").css('opacity', '0.5');
  });
});
```

```css
#btn {
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">test</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you write in comments to your question, if you're looking for listen to url changes, I suggest you to have a look to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212845/how-to-detect-url-changes-with-jquery).

Instead, if you're looking for execute code when that div is on top of HTML page try something like this:

```
$(document).on('scroll', function(){
    if($('your_div').offset() == 0){
        //do stuff when your_div is on top of the page
    }
})
```

This code listen to page scroll, and when your div have an offset of 0px from the top of the page it executes the code in if statement

**EDIT**

If you do this `$(body).css('opacity', '0.2')` you're setting opacity for all in body (specifically for all `<body>`'s children). To set opacity only for some elements, you have to do something tricky: you have to wrap those elements with a div with the same class for all and then set opacity for that class.

I.e.: assuming you wrap that element with a div which class is `opacity`, if you do `$('.opacity').css('opacity', '0.2')` only elements in those div will have opacity setted to 0.2.

Comment: I have this working, in my question I am asking how to set background color of body without taking a button into effect so set background-color: whatever; but not for button